# "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = closing transport due to: connection error"

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, grpc

I am using k8 to host my grpc service.

Sometimes, I am getting the following error (few milliseconds into my request):

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = closing transport due to: connection error: desc = "error reading from server: read tcp <ipaddr>:52220-><internal ip addr>:8070: read: connection reset by peer", received prior goaway: code: NO_ERROR
```

May I ask how will this occur? Could it be that the k8's network is down?

Answer (score 2):

This happened because on server shutdown, it sends an initial GOAWAY to support graceful shutdown. This means your server shut down.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using openshift for deployment. Everything was fine in local environment.
I have my yaml file for diff environments like

```
development.yaml, staging.yaml, production.yaml
```

In `developent.yaml` I used localhost to connect to microservices, i.e

```
auth_service_url: localhost:50051
```

And I didn't notice this before deployment and hence resulting in that error.

I just updated microservice url to point to **`openshift service name`**

```
auth_service_url: np-auth-service:50051 //where np-auth-service is a service name in my openshift environment.
```